# KDB query returns more 2 columns instead of 1 for max filter

Tags: kdb

I just want to create one report where I need max price for each symbol so I wrote following query which works fine on PROD but fails on UAT. So just wanted to know if following query is the appropriate or not.

`select from (select sum price by sym,time,src from Table where date within(2019.12.01;2019.12.31) ) where size=(max;price) fby tier`

Above query returns 2 column for each symbol instead of 1. Following is the result inner query i.e `select sum price by sym,time,src from Table where date within(2019.12.01;2019.12.31)`

```
t:([]time:8#2019.03.11D09:00+"v"$0 4 8 10;sym:8#`GOOG`GOOG`MSFT`MSFT;src:8#`L`O`N`O;price:36.01 35.01 35.5 31.1 39.01 38.01 33.5 32.1;size:8#1427 708 7810 1100)
time                          sym  src price
--------------------------------------------
2019.03.11D09:00:00.000000000 GOOG L   36.01 
2019.03.11D09:00:04.000000000 GOOG O   35.01 
2019.03.11D09:00:08.000000000 MSFT N   35.5  
2019.03.11D09:00:10.000000000 MSFT O   31.1  
2019.03.11D09:00:00.000000000 GOOG L   39.01 
2019.03.11D09:00:04.000000000 GOOG O   38.01 
2019.03.11D09:00:08.000000000 MSFT N   33.5  
2019.03.11D09:00:10.000000000 MSFT O   32.1
```

And output for `select from (select sum price by sym,time,src from Table where date within(2019.12.01;2019.12.31) ) where size=(max;price) fby tier` is :

```
t[0,2,4,7]
time                          sym  src price 
---------------------------------------------
2019.03.11D09:00:00.000000000 GOOG L   36.01 
2019.03.11D09:00:08.000000000 MSFT N   35.5  
2019.03.11D09:00:00.000000000 GOOG L   39.01 
2019.03.11D09:00:10.000000000 MSFT O   32.1
```

Comment: Can you provide some clarification on what tier is? logically size=(max;price) doesn't make much sense. Additionally you probably have too much in the by clause. More detail is required as max price by sym is simply: 

select max price by sym from trades where date within (2014.04.21;2014.04.30)

Comment: I have strong suspicions that this issue hasn't been replicated and portrayed correctly here. From the table you have provided `t`, there are no instances in which  price=size. Assuming that this is not the correct dataset, attempting to find where the sum of price (floats) is = to a long seems ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is something missing with the dataset that you have provided in the question. The results of your inner queries are all floats with remainders, as `size` is a long, it doesn't make any sense that `size=(max;price)` is returning any results.

To answer your question in the most general of sense, to get the max price by sym is

```
select from t where price=(max;price) fby sym
```

Applying this to the inner result you have provided

```
q)select from t where price=(max;price) fby sym
time                          sym  src price size
-------------------------------------------------
2019.03.11D09:00:08.000000000 MSFT N   35.5  7810
2019.03.11D09:00:00.000000000 GOOG L   39.01 1427
```